# class not found in zend services folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, object

I make services folder in my Zend project and i create new php file in that folder. My folder structure is there.

```
<project name>/
    application/
        configs/
            application.ini
        controllers/     
            IndexController.php      
        models/   
            Test.php        
        services/
            SoapClient.php
        views/                
            helpers/
            scripts/
        Bootstrap.php       
    docs/
    library/
    public/          
        .htaccess
        index.php       
    tests/
```

I can use Test.php file using `Application_Model_Test` class. But I can use SoapClient.php file using `Application_Service_SoapClient` or `Application_Services_SoapClient` class name.

Always it show following message.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application_Services_SoapClient' not found in /home/dinuka/workspace/testzend/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 13
```

Please help me. What class should i use in SoapClient.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is correct, but the class should be named, `Application_Service_SoapClient`.

Service is one of the module resource classes that are mapped automatically.

To get it working, just rename the class to `Application_Service_SoapClient` and update all the references to that class if any.  The file name is fine.

These are the default mappings as of 1.11.11:

```
    $this->addResourceTypes(array(
        'dbtable' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model_DbTable',
            'path'      => 'models/DbTable',
        ),
        'mappers' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model_Mapper',
            'path'      => 'models/mappers',
        ),
        'form'    => array(
            'namespace' => 'Form',
            'path'      => 'forms',
        ),
        'model'   => array(
            'namespace' => 'Model',
            'path'      => 'models',
        ),
        'plugin'  => array(
            'namespace' => 'Plugin',
            'path'      => 'plugins',
        ),
        'service' => array(
            'namespace' => 'Service',
            'path'      => 'services',
        ),
        'viewhelper' => array(
            'namespace' => 'View_Helper',
            'path'      => 'views/helpers',
        ),
        'viewfilter' => array(
            'namespace' => 'View_Filter',
            'path'      => 'views/filters',
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Imagine. It is work. I had used Application_Service_SoapClient provisionally.